# Flutter Workmanager plugin implementation missing error occurs in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-plugin

I am trying to use **workmanager: ^0.2.0** plugin for the background process inside the flutter project. While running the application in iOS, it throws an error as below, But in Android plugin is working seamlessly

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel be.tramckrijte.workmanager/foreground_channel_work_manager)
#0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Workmanager.initialize (package:workmanager/src/workmanager.dart:100:30)
#2      main (package:worksample/main.dart:29:15)
```

I manually registered the Workmanager plugin inside the AppDelegate.swift code, still it doesn’t autogenerating plugin registration code inside GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m class file.

Below are my code snippets,

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import workmanager

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    
    WorkmanagerPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { registry in
        AppDelegate.registerPlugins(with: registry)
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    static func registerPlugins(with registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
               GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
          }
       
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
         completionHandler(.alert) 
     }
    
}
```

WorkManager plugin is missed in the below generated file

```
//
//  Generated file. Do not edit.
//

#import "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"

#if __has_include(<flutter_native_timezone/FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin.h>)
#import <flutter_native_timezone/FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin.h>
#else
@import flutter_native_timezone;
#endif

#if __has_include(<shared_preferences/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h>)
#import <shared_preferences/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h>
#else
@import shared_preferences;
#endif

@implementation GeneratedPluginRegistrant

+ (void)registerWithRegistry:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistry>*)registry {
  [FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FlutterNativeTimezonePlugin"]];
  [FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin registerWithRegistrar:[registry registrarForPlugin:@"FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin"]];
}

@end
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by adding the following changes in AppDelegate.swift class.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import workmanager
import shared_preferences

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
 
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    
    WorkmanagerPlugin.register(with: self.registrar(forPlugin: "be.tramckrijte.workmanager.WorkmanagerPlugin"))
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))

    
    WorkmanagerPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { registry in
        AppDelegate.registerPlugins(with: registry)
         FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.register(with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin"))
        
       
           
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    static func registerPlugins(with registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
               GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
          }
       
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
         completionHandler(.alert) 
     }
    
}
```

Comment: I get No such module 'shared_preferences'.

Answer (score 0):

In my acse it works just running the following command on ios folder:

```
pod deintegrate
```

After that I ran:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

The error was gone!