# iOS flutter Accessing Shared Preferences when simulating background fetch in workmanager: MissingPluginException

Tags: ios, flutter, sharedpreferences, background-fetch, flutter-workmanager

I have a project which requires me to access shared preferences in the background to determine what notifications needed to be set. When using this I get this error when simulating background fetch:

> 2021-11-12 10:15:33.351668-0600 Runner[88454:1012638] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart' as w;

w.Workmanager workmanager = w.Workmanager();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
  runApp(const MyApp());
  //setSwitches();
}

void setSwitches() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  myPrefs.setString('key', 'value');
  print("setSwitch func");
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  print("callBackDispatcher");
  workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    setSwitches();

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        
        child: Column(
         
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.alert) // shows banner even if app is in foreground
    }

  class AppDelegate:UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate{
    func application(_ application:UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey:Any]?)->Bool{
          // Other intialization code…
          UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))

          return true
      }
  }

}
```

This is a new project with only workmanager and shared preferences installed. I need to call shared preferences in the background but so far I can't find any solution to this problem. I really don't want to change packages at this point in the project so if there is some workaround that you may see that I'm not I'd be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I simply copied the AppDelegate from here [Flutter Workmanager plugin implementation missing error occurs in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63755922/flutter-workmanager-plugin-implementation-missing-error-occurs-in-ios)

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import workmanager
import shared_preferences

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {


    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    WorkmanagerPlugin.register(with: self.registrar(forPlugin: "be.tramckrijte.workmanager.WorkmanagerPlugin")!)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(TimeInterval(60*15))


    WorkmanagerPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { registry in
        AppDelegate.registerPlugins(with: registry)
        FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.register(with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin")!)



    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

    static func registerPlugins(with registry: FlutterPluginRegistry) {
               GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
          }

    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
         completionHandler(.alert)
     }

}
```